# Can´t to bind or show data from ModelData.read to form in SapUi5

Tags: sapui5

i have a big trouble that's freaking me out, check it out:

This is my xml for a View, program is divided in two differents Views, first of them, a table with navigation and second one is the details, involved in a form.

```
<mvc:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" controllerName="Hello_World.Hello_World.controller.View2"
xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:form="sap.ui.layout.form">
<App>
    <pages>
        <Page title="Detalles" showHeader="true">
            <Button type="Back" press="patras" tooltip="test"/>
            <VBox>
                </VBox>
                    <form:SimpleForm id="formPruebas" maxContainerCols="2" layout="ResponsiveGridLayout" labelSpanL="5" labelSpanM="4" labelSpanS="6" title="Formulario">
                        <Label text="CustomerID"/>
                            <Text text="{jsonmodel>CustomerID}"/>

                        <Label text="CompanyName"/>
                            <Text text="{CompanyName}"/>
                        <Label text="ContactTitle" />
                            <Text text="{ContactTitle}"/>

                        <Label text="Adress"/>
                            <Text text="{Adress}"/> 

                        <Label text="City"/>
                            <Text text="{City}"/>

                        <Label text="PostalCode"/>
                            <Text text="{PostalCode}"/>

                        <Label text="Country" />
                            <Text text="{i18n>Country}"/>

                        <Button text="Aceptar" type="Accept">
                            <layoutData>
                                <FlexItemData growFactor="1" />
                            </layoutData>
                        </Button>

                        <Button text="Editar" width="100px">
                            <layoutData>
                                <FlexItemData growFactor="1" />
                            </layoutData>
                        </Button>

                    </form:SimpleForm>

        </Page>
    </pages>
</App>
```

Alright so this is my controller:

```
onInit: function() {
            var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
            oRouter.getRoute("View2").attachMatched(this._onRouteMatched, this);
            },

            _onRouteMatched: function(oEvent) {
                var idDevuelto = oEvent.getParameter("arguments").data;
                var idCompleto = "/Customers('" + idDevuelto + "')"; 
                //var oForm = this.getView().byId("formPruebas");
                var oForm = this.getView().byId("formPruebas");
                var serviceUrl = "myurl";
                var oModelData = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(serviceUrl,{
                    JSON:true,
                    useBatch: false
                });

                oModelData.read(idCompleto, {
                    success: function (oData) {
                        sap.m.MessageToast.show(oData.CustomerID);
                        var oModel = new JSONModel(oData.results);
                        oForm.setModel(oModel.results);

                    },
                    error: function (oError) {
                        sap.m.MessageToast.show("No funca");
                    }
                });



            },
```

However the result is not showing on my view when i run the program, any idea?
PD: I'm pretty noob on sapui5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution of the problem, if you check the XML code at the beginning of the question , you realize there is not path in Form element. 
In mi first view i have a table with id and a PATH which i don't have in the Form so the fastest way i solve it is to put in the XML a slash, an example:

```
<form:SimpleForm id="formPruebas" maxContainerCols="2" layout="ResponsiveGridLayout" labelSpanL="5" labelSpanM="4" labelSpanS="6" title="Formulario">
                    <Label text="CustomerID"/>
                        <Text text="{/CustomerID}"/> // the slash i mean
```

With that fix, i only do oForm.setModel(oModel) so everything is connected and works 
fine, i want to share this information if more people deal with the same error as i did.
Thanks all ideas.